# webhooks for jenkins multibranch pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I configured webhooks in my github repository with events "Send me everything.". If i create any new branch in repository, github is delivering the webhooks perfectly, but build is not triggered in jeknins job .
Configured jenkins multibranch pipeline job with this repository, but i am unable to find options like "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" and "GitHub Pull Request Builder" like in freestyle/maven jobs. do i need to install any plugins? any help appreciated.

attaching screenshot of my job's configuration.

I went through similar queries in stackoverflow, but i didn't find any clue. all answers are based on freestyle/maven jobs.

[image: job_configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your Jenkinsfile contains a check for "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling". This can be done by declaring the following in your Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        githubPush()
    }
}
```

Link to documentation:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.githubPush

Comment: @Stqs Yes, I believe that's what I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the below Url :

`http://yourjenkins/project/*yourprojectname*` on "Add Webhook" in git service provider.

No configuration required in Jenkins multibranch job it will automatically start the branch indexing.